# Does this SQL query produce right results?

Tags: mysql

The query is intended to show all records from tbltransactions grouped by customerid and pick customer names from tblcustomers where customerids of both tables match.

```
select 
    a.customerid, 
    sum(transactionamount) as transactionamount, 
    b.customername 
from 
    tbltransactions a,
    tblcustomers b
where 
    a.customerid = b.customerid 
group by customerid 
order by b.customername
```

Does this query assures that all records in tbltransactions are displayed properly. I'm new to MySQL and php. Thanks

Secondly:

when I add "a." to sum(transactionamount) as transactionamount" it produces error why is it so? Moreover what kind of join query it is.

Comment: Why not try and run that query in your console/query window and see if that gets the result you're looking for?

Comment: It'd be 100 times easier for you to run this query and tell **us** if it works or not

Comment: You Should use INNER JOIN http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: so far query works good but I am not sure if it is right for any dataset therefore asked this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select a.customerid, sum(transactionamount) as transactionamount, b.customername from   tbltransactions a INNER JOIN tblcustomers b ON a.customerid = b.customerid group by customerid order by b.customername
```

Comment: Thanks but why should it be better than the query in question? Please explain for my knowledge

Comment: I have also mentioned link (Inner Join Tutorial) in comment.

Comment: it says "The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables."

Comment: unfortunately I need all records from tbltransactions and only those from tblcustomers where customerids match

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI SQL, non-aggregated column can't be selected when `GROUP BY` is used. Only aggregated column and aggregated function can be selected.
In your query, `b.customername` can't be selected because only `a.customerid` is aggregated column.

But MySQL implements non-standard. So your query works well without syntax error and produces right results if `a.customerid` and `b.customername` has one-to-one relationship.

But valid SQL Syntax is as belows:

```
SELECT a.customerid, transactionamount,
    b.customername
FROM (
    SELECT 
        customerid, 
        SUM(transactionamount) as transactionamount,
    FROM 
        tbltransactions
    GROUP BY customerid 
) AS a INNER JOIN tblcustomers b ON a.customerid = b.customerid 
ORDER BY b.customername;
```

You would get an error when you execute your query with `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`

Thank you for read my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for the valid syntax!